# Upgrade Pre-Installed Windows 11 Home to Pro in setup

Tags: windows, microsoft-365

I have some HP OEM systems with Windows 11 Home preinstalled. Since they all should connect to a MS365 company account, they need to have a Pro versions (at least as far as I know). Otherwise the setup wizard does not allow company accounts and only accepts private Microsoft accounts.

Now that I have Windows Pro Keys for all the systems, whats the easiest way to set those systems up? Is there any way to add the key in the setup wizard? Should I sign in with a private one, upgrade to pro and restore the system? Or should I just reinstall all of them from scratch with a USB boot device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would reinstall over with a USB stick to make it easy as if you are managed from the cloud you will be prompted for the OOBE at the first boot to join the tenant, which make the integration easier.

Your other option would be to ugrade the version and do a sysprep to restart the OOBE, but I prefer the first solution as it's cleaner IMO.

Comment: Just out of interest: would it be possible to initialize the system with a private account, upgrade to Win Pro and use the Windows reset feature after the upgrade? Will the system still be licenced as a pro version or reset to the OEMs default? This way I wouldn't need a boot medium for all the devices and it seams clean, too.

Comment: @tris Hi, yes you can reset after the ugrade by using the Sysprep /generalize /shutdown /oobe command's line.

Comment: Thank you! One last question: if I use the regular "Reset PC" via the GUI (I only know the German names, but guess you know what I mean): what kind of "sysprep" does it call internally? Both calling "keep personal data" and "remove everything"

Comment: @tris Never used the GUI's way, but the gui's way if you select "remove everything" will reinstall Windows over and will use the internet to get the iso, it can be a bottleneck if a lot of computer need to be done.

Comment: Ah, ok! But it will pick the ISO corresponding the installed version? So in my case Win Pro would be taken?

Comment: @tris I assume yes, as the product is activated with that key, but if it check the bios burnin key it could revert to that iso, it would be to test out.